# Deploying maven project

Tags: java, compilation, maven-2, wildfly, web-deployment

I am Deploying my maven project and it brings this error

> "javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: tripticket.vehicle.model.Vehicle cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;".

And code indicates no error.

Comment: Can't help anyone who insists there's no errors and everything's fine when they see an exception.  First step is admitting you have a problem.  Go to the line number of the file called out by the exception and look at the code.

Comment: Can you add your complete error/deployment log?

Comment: Can you please add some more information related to the class in error. And also more information on the logs would be helpful in debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Error but a RuntimeException - those are two different things in Java. IDE won't mark code which can produce a RuntimeException.

Furthermore, looks like you are trying to cast tripticket.vehicle.model.Vehicle on java.lang.Object somewhere in your code.